# How to use path aliases in React v17 TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am trying to create some shorter, more readable imports such as instead of `../../../../input` I can do `@components/input`. I have tried setting the paths in a separate "tsconfig.paths.json" and extending the default tsconfig with it but I still get the error: `aliased imports are not supported`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?